# AG Grid: center checkbox alone in cell

Tags: ag-grid, vuejs3, ag-grid-vue

Versions:

```
vueJS: 3.0.0
bootstrap: 5.0.0-beta3
ag-grid-community: 26.1.0
ag-grid-vue3: 26.1.2
```

See screenshot below.  In my `columnDefs` for `ag-grid`, I have specified `checkboxSelection: true` for the `Pending` column.  I do not wish to render any text in that column.  Rather, I wish for a single checkbox that is centered in each cell.  Can this be done?  As things stand now, the checkbox is left-aligned in the cell.

Here is the columnDef for `Pending`:

```
{ headerName: "Pending", field: "pending", sortable: true, editable: true, checkboxSelection: true, cellStyle: () => getPageStatus() },
```

And here is styling for column headers:

```
  .ag-header-cell-label {
    justify-content: center;
  }
```

Thanks for looking into it.

[image]

Comment: After inspecting the DOM for ag-grid cells housing the checkboxes, I was able to center checkboxes under `Pending` column header with this styling:    `.ag-cell-wrapper { justify-content: center; }`.  But I was really hoping for a well-defined way to do this from within the document API for AG Grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I scratched up a general solution that explains how to render custom HTML elements within a grid cell.  Most of this solution is based on pre-existing articles and blogs out there.  Note the data model here (rendered to the grid) assumes a `pending` property.

#### <template>

```
    <ag-grid-vue
      class="ag-theme-alpine"
      :frameworkComponents="frameworkComponents"
      :columnDefs="columnDefs"
      :rowData="getRowData"
      rowSelection="multiple"
      domLayout="autoHeight"
      editType="fullRow"
      @grid-ready="onGridReady">
    </ag-grid-vue>
```

#### <script>

```
import CheckboxRenderer from '@/components/CheckboxRenderer.vue';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      frameworkComponents: {
        checkboxRenderer: CheckboxRenderer
      },
      columnDefs: [
            { headerName: "Pending", field: "pending", sortable: true, editable: true,
          cellStyle: () => getPageStatus(), cellRenderer: 'checkboxRenderer', valueGetter: params => params ? null : null },
      ]
    }
  }
};
```

#### CheckboxRenderer.vue

```
<template>
  <input ref="eGui" @click="checkedHandler" type="checkbox" v-model="params.data.pending" class="ag-input-field-input ag-checkbox-input" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "CheckboxRenderer",
  props: {
    params: Object
  },
  methods: {
    getGui() {
      return this.$refs.eGui;
    },
    checkedHandler(e) {
      let checked = e.target.checked;
      let colId = this.params.column.colId;
      this.params.node.setDataValue(colId, checked);
    }
  },
};
</script>

<style>
.ag-checkbox-input {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
</style>
```